# Как проверить включен ли wi-fi на устройстве?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Мне нужно проверить включен ли wi-fi на устройстве и подключен ли он к какой-либо сети(точке доступа wifi).

Comment: Пожалуйста если мой ответ помог вам, то выберите его как "Правильный ответ", если же нет, то напишите что я упустил. Это нужно не для меня, а для других пользователей у которых может возникнуть похожая проблема. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная возможность присутствует в [Xamarin.Essentials](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/?context=xamarin/android)

Вот ссылка на [Xamarin.Essentials: Connectivity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android)

И собственно сам пример отттуда же:

```
var profiles = Connectivity.ConnectionProfiles;
if (profiles.Contains(ConnectionProfile.WiFi))
{
    // Active Wi-Fi connection.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Проверить подключение к `Wifi` на `Android` можно вот так:

```
using Android.Net;
var cm = (ConnectivityManager)GetSystemService(Application.ConnectivityService);
bool isConnected = cm.ActiveNetworkInfo.IsConnected;
```

Если вам нужно проверять не только на `Android`, то вот еще для `iOS`:

```
using SystemConfiguration;
NetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
bool isConnected = new NetworkReachability(new System.Net.IPAddress(0)).TryGetFlags(out flags);
```

и `Windows`:

```
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;
var profile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
bool isConnected = profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() != NetworkConnectivityLevel.None;
```

Или можете использовать плагин `ConnectivityPlugin`.

Поподробнее на эту тему и про плагин можете почитать [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/10.2.php)